# Split an ArrayList in Java into two sublists at the occurrence of a special character

Tags: java, hibernate, arraylist, hashset

I have a Typed arraylist

```
List<ABC> DbList = new ArrayList<ABC>();
```

where ABC is the entity class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_database")
public class ABC implements Serializable  {

@Id
private String datname;
```

The contents are something like:

Xyz_2015

Abc_2016

and so on.

I intend to split this arraylist into two sublists where the first list contains :
Xyz

Abc
and so on

and the second list contains the years only. I also want to get rid of "_"

Any ideas on how I should approach the solution?

Comment: What is `ABC`? How is `Xyz_2015` represented in that class? Also, show what you've attempted and explain where you're stuck. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: loop arraylist then split it then insert into sublist.

Comment: @shmosel: ABC is my entity class where the data comes from a table ABC. So far I tried looking up for possible ways to split the contents of a list but couldn't come across anything which gave me any leads. So any idea on how to do it would be a great help to get me started.

Comment: You can't split an "entity", unless that entity is a string. You're not (necessarily) going to find a resource that teaches you how to split a list down the middle. Programming is about breaking down a problem and solving each piece using familiar building blocks. In this case, you need to create two new lists, iterate over the source list, split each item and add each side to one of the new lists. Each of those points is relatively simple and can easily be researched for more information.

Comment: `String.split()`.  See the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @shmosel: There's only field in the entity class and it's of type String. And I'm putting that in this arraylist.I have edited my question and displayed the entity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split list of Entinites to two lists of Strings you could use:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ABC item : list) {
        String[] subs = item.getDatname().split("_");
        names.add(subs[0]);
        years.add(subs[1]);
    }
```

Assuming `list` is a `ArrayList<ABC>`